# Copy image from browser memory to python memory using selenium

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, browser

I want to transfer images loaded in a browser to python memory. The images have been loaded in the browser and have links associated with them. However, I do not want to download them again using urllib in python and just want to use the images which are already in browser memory. Is it possible to do it using selenium?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot really access "browser memory" using selenium, but you could do a couple of things depending on what you need.

1. Create a snapshot of the page, which will also include the image. If you want to preserve the image page had at some moment of time (e.g. captcha), this is the best way.
2. Using right-click menu "Save image as", as shown [here](http://software-testing-tutorials-automation.blogspot.ca/2015/01/download-and-save-image-using-selenium.html). Not very reliable and browser-dependant, but can be useful in some cases.
3. Also browser-dependent: in some browsers (e.g. Chrome), you can also navigate to `chrome://view-http-cache/` using selenium, and select your image from the list. It will show you the request by which the image was received, including binary data of the image. You can then reassemble it in python. This is a lot of work though, so it should be really worth it. I didn't try that approach.